# Setting the generator (firebird) for a model field of Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

For example:

I have the following table:

```
TABLE_EXAMPLO 
-----------
ID         
NAME
```

And following Generator:

```
TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN
```

How do I map the entity to which the Entity Framework can call the generator to new records?

In NHibernate was necessary something like this in `ClassMap<T>`:

```
Id(t => t.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN").Column("ID");
// or
Id(t => t.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN").Column("ID");
```

And EntityFramwork is this possible?

> Note: I have already (in legacy system) one in Firebird database in this format, with generator for the primary key (no triggers).

Comment: set the ID to identity in the EDMX designer: http://blog.cincura.net/230841-generated-primary-key-in-entity-framework-model-from-firebird/

Comment: @magicandre1981, Ok, but then I have to create triggers for the generators work as identidy to the tables. And that's exactly what I would like to avoid.

Comment: You can have a look on similar questions about sequences on SQL Server. Anyway, you won't find a similar feature on EF (I mean similar to NHibernate sequence handling).

Comment: why don't you want to use triggers?

Comment: @magicandre1981. Why already have a legacy database with more than 600 tables, and would not want to have to change my tables, since that way without any structural change already works well with other ORM (NHibernate) and the legacy system in other technology (Delphi).

Comment: the source of EF6.x is available on github: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6 Fork it, implement the feature, create a pull request so that EF6.2 support the feature.